# Validate request parameters in a spring-data-rest application

Tags: spring-data-rest, querydsl

I am exposing REST APIs using spring-data-rest and do not want to write custom controllers. To enable filtering on multiple fields I am using QueryDsl and want to validate request parameters. I don't see any hook where I can trigger validation. 
The only option I have is to add manual validation code in customize method of QuerydslBinderCustomizer.

Below is how my repository class looks like

public interface TestRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository,
        QuerydslPredicateExecutor, QuerydslBinderCustomizer {

```
@Override
default void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QTest test) {
    bindings.excludeUnlistedProperties(true);
    bindings.including(test.name, test.number);

    bindings.bind(test.name).first((StringPath path, String value) -> {
        return path.containsIgnoreCase(value);
    });
    bindings.bind(test.number).first((StringPath path, String value) -> {
        return path.containsIgnoreCase(value);
    });
}
```

}